How to properly use Generic Packager to pack Nested TLV fields?
My ISO spec defines some fields like follows: Dataset ID + Length + TLV fields
There can be many Dataset IDs in this Field 34, and each dataset ID can contain many tags, and all of the tags follow TLV format as well.
I'm trying to utilize JPOS Generic Packager to set these nested TLV fields, but I'm not sure I'm doing it the correct way.
My packager definition:
<isofieldpackager
        id="34"
        length="1535"
        name="Acceptance Environment Data (TLV Format)"
        class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLHBINARY"
        tagSize="2"
        lenSize="2"
        tagMapper="org.jpos.iso.packager.TTDecimalTagMapper"
        packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericTaggedFieldsPackager">
    <isofieldpackager
            id="01"
            length="999"
            name="DS ID 01"
            class="com.model.IFB_TTLLBINARY"
            tagSize="2"
            lenSize="2"
            tagMapper="org.jpos.iso.packager.TTDecimalTagMapper"
            packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericTaggedFieldsPackager">
        <isofield
                id="128"
                length="99"
                name="Tag 80 in hex (128 decimal)"
                class="com.model.IFB_TTLLBINARY"/>
    </isofieldpackager>
</isofieldpackager>

My IFB_TTLLBINARY class:
public class IFB_TTLLBINARY extends ISOTagBinaryFieldPackager {

/** Used for the GenericPackager. */
public IFB_TTLLBINARY() {
    super(0,null, BinaryPrefixer.B, NullPadder.INSTANCE,
            LiteralBinaryInterpreter.INSTANCE, BinaryPrefixer.B);
}


public IFB_TTLLBINARY(int len, String description) {
    super(len, description, BinaryPrefixer.B, NullPadder.INSTANCE,
            LiteralBinaryInterpreter.INSTANCE, BinaryPrefixer.B);
    }

   }

And I am attempting to set the field like this:
    ISOMsg msg = new ISOMsg();
    msg.setPackager(packager);
    msg.setMTI("0100");
    msg.set("34.01.128",ISOUtil.hex2byte("F1F2F3F4"));

This gets me very close to my desired output, but I have 2 problems.

I can see on my company's audits for this transaction that the field being sent is 00068004F1F2F3F4, which I am expecting a value of 01068004F1F2F3F4 instead. So that first Dataset ID doesn't seem to be getting set properly.

I would like to be able to set the subfield based on the hex value instead of the decimal value, since the name of the datasets and tags can be alphanumeric. For example: msg.set("34.01.4A") . It seems that I might first convert the subfield ID into decimal before I can set it in the ISOMsg.


